# What is the #shadow-root inside elements?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've seen something strange today. Look at the pics related to the post (below). I've made an input[type="text"]. Its the "1" on the screen picture. It's css looks something like that;

```
table tbody input {
    width: 40px;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Just an ordinary input, besides this one doesn't have any border.

Then, I looked at the dev-tools, and I saw something what I've never seen before. The "#shadow-root" and a div inside an input.

I know, that dev-tools adds something by itself to display hints on the original webpage. However, I'm really curious why it adds a div inside an input, and how is that actually possible to render anything like that on webkit engine.

Chrome dev-tools are somehow weird last time, I had some issues with it. For example, it doubled the style.css file and forgets to load another one what was the cause of the terrible look of jquery calendar (only when loaded on my browser).

It's probably not a bug, but a feature, but I'd love to know more about it

[image: Input visible in browser (it's not straight, adhoc screen)]

[image: This input visible from the dev-tools side]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the *Shadow DOM*.

Just click at the options and disable the "***Show Shadow DOM***" options..

The w3c draft can be found at https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/shadow/index.html

and in regards to Chrome see http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/inspecting-the-shadow-dom-in-google-chrome-inspector/

Comment: Hi, kind of late here, but i'm having an issue where the Shadow DOM (#shadow-root) is adding a breaking line at the top of the page. I already turned off the Shadow DOM option, any ideas?

Comment: @andufo the shadow DOM discussed here refers to the developer tools only. How do you know that your problem is with the Shadow DOM and not the actual HTML/CSS ?

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli i already ran several checks, it is definitely only happening in Chrome. Something is adding 5 blank lines after <body>

Comment: @andufo if you can put it online somewhere i can take a look.

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110662/browsers-are-adding-a-blank-block-after-the-body-tag

Answer (score 6):

As Gaby Petrioli pointed out, this is the Shadow DOM. It is created by the browser to provide an encapsulation interface in HTML, for third-party libraries, et al.

*A big problem for 3rd-party libraries (and browser extensions etc) that inject new HTML into existing pages is that there may be existing CSS (or JavaScript) on that page that might modify the same classnames or IDs as those being injected - and mayhem could ensue.* Encapsulation is needed!

Encapsulation (aka scoping) is an OOP concept wherein objects can restrict access to their own data so that third-party code cannot arbitrarily wipe it out.

HTML lacks any encapsulation capabilities, which is especially a problem for third-party libraries (jQuery, twitter buttons, etc). Shadow DOM was invented ***to provide functional encapsulation for the various subtrees of the DOM. This is achieved by keeping functional subtrees separate from the document tree (and each other). This separation of shadow DOM subtrees is known as the shadow boundary. CSS rules and DOM queries do not cross the shadow boundary, and thus provide encapsulation.(1)***

As Dominic Cooney put it: ***Here is a fundamental problem that makes widgets built out of HTML and JavaScript hard to use: The DOM tree inside a widget isn't encapsulated from the rest of the page. This lack of encapsulation means your document stylesheet might accidentally apply to parts inside the widget; your JavaScript might accidentally modify parts inside the widget; your IDs might overlap with IDs inside the widget; and so on.(2)***

Shadow DOM solves these problems in modern web development:

- Isolated DOM: A component's DOM is self-contained **(e.g. document.querySelector() won't return nodes in the component's shadow DOM)**.
- Scoped CSS: CSS defined inside shadow DOM is scoped to it. **Style rules don't leak out and page styles don't bleed in.**
- Composition: Design a declarative, markup-based API for your component.
- Simplifies CSS - Scoped DOM means you can use simple CSS selectors, more generic id/class names, and not worry about naming conflicts.
- Productivity - Think of apps in chunks of DOM rather than one large (global) page.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) by MDN explains how/why to use the Shadow DOM yourself. Tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

Further Reading:

[Google Developer's updated article on ShadowDOM (2020)](https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/)

[MDN - Web Components (including Shadow DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

[Basic introductory description of the Shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/)

[***(1) A more complete technical description*** - the second part of this article explains how to use the Shadow DOM yourself](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-basics-of-the-shadow-dom/)

[(2) Dominic Cooney's article: Shadow DOM 101 - now OUTDATED (See Google article above)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220211192842/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

[Shadow DOM - W3C Working Draft 17 June 2014](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)