# Change text of a div inside a "shadow root" with closing input tag

Tags: jquery, shadow-dom

Lets say I have the following input box with a #shadow-root (user-agent) as div:
And yes, I know... input is a void Tag and doesn't have an closing tag. But in my case it has and I have to deal with what I get.

```
<input type="text" id="myID"> 
#shadow-root (user-agent) 
   <div>This is a test</div> 
</input>
```

I've to change the text between the divs.

I'm pretty new to shadow-doms, so my best guess was:

```
var el = $('#myID');
el.shadowRoot.text('I changed the text');
```

My problem is that shadowRoot is always undefined. While fiddling around with jsfiddle I'm not even able to get the div (ignoring my shadowRoot problem in the first place) - maybe because the input tags are so weird? Found [Shadow root div inside input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819327/shadow-root-div-inside-input) , so I guess closing input tags are a thing with shadow-doms.

Thank you so much in advance!

http://tpcg.io/_DAK1OF

This whole code:
[image: my Code]

Answer (score 0):

`input`, `textarea` and many other *complex* tags are created by the Browser Vendors (Apple, Mozilla, Chromium), that is why you see `user-agent` in the Inspector.

Yes, they use Web Components technology, but they are **not** created with the Custom Elements API (allowing **users** to create Web Components)

Thus you/user can not change anything in them, they don't have an accesible shadowRoot.

The `input` tag has its own interface; see the `text` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Had you searched StackOverflow, you would have found a similar question from 10 years ago: [Shadow root div inside input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819327/shadow-root-div-inside-input?noredirect=1&lq=1)